# I don't under stand this code - python

Tags: python

This is a code in python, I don't understand the re.compile function .. could any one help me with this regular expresion syntax?

```
  file = open("C:\Users\Suleiman JK\Desktop\hello-world-reverse-uri.pdf")
  data = file.read()
  rxcountpages = re.compile(r"$\s*/Type\s*/Page[/\s]", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
  print rxcountpages.findall(data)
```

Comment: what you don't understand in third line? Does it work well ? what is your objective?

Comment: yes it works correctly. it finds the number of pages in pdf file
but I don't understand the combination

Comment: $\s*/Type\s*/Page[/\s is the pattern in regurar expresion

"\s" mean space
"*" mean zero or more ocurrences
"$" mean the endo of string or line , but I dont know very well in this situation with this opions (re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
"[]" mean or, in this case is / or space (\s)
You are looking for at the end of line the text "/Type /Page" or: 
    " /Type /Page"
    "  /Type /Page"
    " /Type  /Page"
    "/Type   /Page"
    "/Type   /Page "
    "/Type   /Page/"
    "/Type /Page "
    " /Type   /Page "
    "/Type   /Page/"
     ...

You can reed more in https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The Python code here is trying to `open` a file then `read` the contents of the file in memory  (into the `data` variable) and then it applies a `regular expression` to get the count of the pages and finally prints it. What exactly you did not understand here? Pinpointing your exact question and searching lit bit more before posting a question will help you more.

Comment: the point that I don't understand is this
"$\s*/Type\s*/Page[/\s]"

Comment: This would be better served as a comment.